# Autocomplete Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to use autocomplete from this tutorial and adapt to my project : https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview
The problem is after I changed several structure of the code it becomes an error can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

```js
myControl = new FormControl();
 filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;
  
   this.configSerivce.getConfig().subscribe( (data:Line)  => {
        this.line=data;
        this.line[this.i].status = false; //added new attribute status
        this.i++;
    });
    
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
    
  private _filter(value: string,line : any): any[] {
    const filterValue = parseInt(value);
    return line.filter(option => option.lineNumber === filterValue);
  }
```

```css
export interface Line {
    baseVersion?: string;
    netVersion?: number;
    mandator?: string;
    lineNumber?: number;
    shortName?: string;
    name?: string;
    variants?: Array<Variant>;
}
```

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text"  matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.lineNumber">
        {{option.lineNumber}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please share your filteredOptions value?

Comment: updated the code , using a model that I call from a service

Comment: You can't iterate over an Observable. You need to unwrap it with async pipe first to get the actual array. `*ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"`

Comment: Either use the subscribe method or async to unwrap the data. The better option is async.

Comment: I've done what you asked, but how do I display all the related elements and not just one object? Can you please help me out . Updated the code